# Check if AVQueuePlayer is playing?

Tags: avaudioplayer, avqueueplayer

I'm trying to develop multi files audio player so I used AVQueuePlayer, I need to check whenever the player is playing a sound or paused?

For AvAudioPlayer, I have the property "isPlaying", but for AVQueuePlayer how to check it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if AVQueuePlayer is playing by checking if rate of queue player object is more than 0

```
-(BOOL)isPlaying {
    return self.queuePlayer.rate > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:
```

to know when the player starts playing some file as explained in this url:
http://www.artermobilize.com/blog/2014/02/28/detect-when-audio-playback-begins-with-avplayer-in-ios/

also you can use this code to know when the playback is finished:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // your code here
}
```